# Why <tr> is not removed when click on the No button?

Tags: jquery

What's wrong with the code?

```
$('<tr><td><input type="button" value="No" /></td></tr>')
.appendTo('table')
.find('input[type=text]')
.select()
.end()
.find("input[type='text'][value='No']")
.click(function() {$(this).parents('tr').remove();})
```

Comment: shouldn't that be `input[type='button']`? though I don't see the reason for the second find, select or end either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're selecting type=text at your selectors. Change them to type=button.

```
$('<tr><td><input type="button" value="No" /></td></tr>')
.appendTo('table')
.find('input[type=button]')
.select()
.end()
.find("input[type='button'][value='No']")
.click(function() {$(this).parents('tr').remove();})
```

Comment: he's appending that to a table, so it may actually exists